# Is an actor always a stakeholder in a UseCase diagram?

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

This is a question confused me for a rather long time.

For the definition of `stakehoder`, I can understand that a stakeholder is not always an actor. For example, to build a nuclear power station, the National Nuclear Safety Administration may be a stakeholder, but it does not interact with the station, so it's not an actor.

But on the other hand, **is an actor always a stakeholder**?

Consider this: we build a underground cable system, and some rat bite the cable. In usecase analysis, I would like to model the rat as an actor, but it is definitely not a stakeholder of this system.

Comment: What would the UC be you are thiking about? "Bite the cable"?

Comment: @qwerty_so After some more thinking, such UC does not exist, as the system do not provide extra functions to drive off rats, and the interest of rats are not take into account.

Comment: There are two good answers, though your question turned out to be "wrong" ;-) There's always place for anyone to learn something. Consider upvoting to at least honor the effort.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the rat has an interest in not being electrocuted. So, it *is* a stakeholder. The question is, how important you consider it to be. Probably not so much.

Also, you would not analyse the use case *"satisfy hunger for cables"*. Rather you should analyse how to *"protect cable against rat bites"*. Both are valid use cases, but I assume, that you don‘t want your system to be used in the first way and therefore you should not model it. The second one is only a use case, if your system shall have functions to drive off rats.

The UML doesn‘t say much about how to describe use cases. I always recommend to describe them from the viewpoint of the stakeholder for whom the result is of value.

Comment: The latter would be a constraint rather than a use case. So probably the OP should be queried whether modeling a rat would make sense in any context.

Comment: I think the interest of a stakeholder would make some design decision happen. But for a rat, it does not has special need to the system, and if we do not care the harm caused by electrocuted, does it still be treated as a stakeholder?

Comment: @dumeng If the rat is a pet, we would consider it an important stakeholder. If we don‘t care for its well being, its interests would be of no concern to us, but it still is a stakeholder. You have to decide about the priority of all stakeholders and you probably give the rat a very low priority.

Comment: @querty_so _„protect cable against rat bites“_ can be a use case. As always it depends on whether you need to analyse it, to find system functions. If you simply make the cable stronger, a requirement would be enough. If your base architecture includes a robot that crawls along the cable and drives off rats, a use case analysis is helpful.

Comment: Got the idea. Actually I think the underground cable system has no such functions to drive off rats, so no such use case. 
And this story is actually a real one, and they finally make the pipe smaller so the rats could not enter to bite the cable.  Model this as a requirement should be more reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

## In short

Yes, every actor is always stakeholder.  But not every stakeholder is an actor.

## Some more thoughts:

#### First definition

In the UML specifications, there is no definition of stakeholders. But it is said that:

> [A use case] specifies a set of behaviors performed by that subject [i.e. the system], which yields an observable result that is of value for Actors or other stakeholders of the subject.

This wording also suggests that actors are stakeholders: if they weren't, the word "other" wouldn't be needed.

By the way, this clearly eliminates the rat from the suspected actors, since the cabling system is not supposed to produce results of value for rats. And the result that could be observed on the rats is not of value for the other stakeholders.

#### How are stakeholders related to use cases?

Many systems produce an observable result that is of value for the actor interacting with the system:  the actor benefits of cash after a withdrawal, the actor could achieve a task with the system, etc...

But the value is not always for the actor.  If you walk through a body scanner at the airport, as a user you might not fully value the results of being scanned yourself.  But the airport, the airline, homeland and security, and the other passengers may very well value the result of the use case.  This shows that not all stakeholders who have interest in a system, are necessarily users.

#### Second definition

As strange as it may sound, the [SWEBOK](https://www.computer.org/education/bodies-of-knowledge/software-engineering) does not define the stakeholder either.  They just enumerate some examples, such as users, customers, regulators etc.  [ISO 21500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_21500) does also have a definition by example.

Moreover, we must keep in mind that the interest of a stakeholder is not only the own benefit, but could be the opposite.  If your neighbor installs a video surveillance system with a camera that captures the entry of your house, you're neither the customer, nor the user, but you will probably be a stakeholder perceiving a threat for your right to privacy.

A popular definition is therefore the PMI's:

> An individual, group or organization that may affect, be affected or perceive itself to be affected by a decision, activity or outcome of a project, programme or portfolio.

We can cross check that according to this definition that all actors are stakeholders, since they will be affected by the future system.

#### And the rats?

Rats are in principle not actors of an underground cabling system, as the system is not build for providing them value nor to involve them to provide value to other stakeholders.  Rats could be considered as  stakeholders if we'd extend the concept to animals: they may be affected or think to be affected by all this cables.  Bust most probably,  they are simply a source of malfunctions in the system's environment.

*This reminds me a story that an old system engineer told me 30 years ago, and that happened to him at the begin of his career, probably another 30 years before.  It was on his first bigger computing project, a large electromechanical computer designed to compute the payroll of a large organisation.  For some reasons,  there were some mistakes every month, but never the same.  After months of (expensive) debugging,  they found out that some rats indeed have eaten the hull of some cables in the floor space under the very large computer, and if a rat by chance walked on the wires at the wrong moment, it closed random circuits that were supposed to stay open.  A more modern version of the [first bug](https://www.nationalgeographic.org/thisday/sep9/worlds-first-computer-bug/)?*

Comment: Here too: the question should be "what is the UC the OP is talking about?". I think it will clearly result in "there is no such use case".

Comment: The rat will definitely observe the result: It will get electrocuted. Please note that the definition explicitly allows _„a result that is of value for […] other stakeholders“_. So, the stakeholder seeing a _value_ in the result is not necessarily identical to the one seeing the _result_.

Comment: Is being electrocuted of value for the rat?  Is electrocuting rat an observable result of value for another stakeholder of the subject?

Comment: My point is, that the rat _can_ be an actor in a use case. For example if the cable system needs functions to drive off rats. In this case the operator will see a value in electrocuting them. If the system has no such use case, I would still show the rat as an actor in the system context. The UML says _„An Actor models a type of role played by an entity that interacts with the subjects of its associated UseCases“_. That means nothing is defined for a direct association to the system. It is however allowed, and the interpretation that the actor interacts with the associated system makes sense.

Comment: Stakeholder has a definition in SysML. It says that a `Stakeholder` can be applied to an actor or class (not association).  Does this means that there are actors which are not stakeholder?   As the spec does not say `Stakeholder`  **must** apply to actor.

Comment: @dumeng SysML may give another meaning to the the terms. However in the UML context, a stakeholder is not a modeling element. It is a reality outside of the model: who is paying for the system and expects some economic advantage or who is against the system may not change the content and scope of the system, but it could be helpful to know for analysing the requirements. The users of the system are stakeholders because the system will impact their lives in one way or another.

Comment: The only actors where this principle could be questioned are system actors (i.e. autonomous systems who are interacting with the subject). But these actors, at the level of the use case, could perfectly be replaced with a human actor playing the same role. Later,  not, because an API is not an UI, but in this case the system actor would still be a proxy for the stakeholders of the other system.